# Unable to Install any package using homebrew

Tags: installation, homebrew

I'm newbie to macOS. I ran into an issue where when ever I try to install any package. The dependencies get downloaded but it doesn’t get installed. Please help me regarding this.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

The issues was the permissions of the system.
What I did is that I reinstalled brew and then I found that
New command for users on macOS High Sierra as it is not possible to `chown` on `/usr/local`:

`bash/zsh`:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

`fish`:

```
sudo chown -R (whoami) (brew --prefix)/*
```

Reference: [Can't chown /usr/local in High Sierra](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228)